# Issue with saving objects using Spring Solr data

Tags: spring, solr, spring-data-solr

I have an application where I am using spring datasolr to save data. Now I have an object PhoneDocument that has lot of fields: String, boolean. They are getting properly saved in solr. Even Collection is getting properly saved in solr.

How ever if I use an object like SimDocument in PhoneDocument, data form SimDocument is not saved in solr.

Before posting my code I wanted to know if its even possible to have a scenario where your Document has a custom object and when you save the Document(PhoneDocument) the data that was stored in the custom object(SimDocument) will be saved as well

Answer (score 0):

Solr does not support nested structures. This means you'll have to flatten data in a way that fits the index.

You can register your own [Converter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter.html) as `@ReadingConverter` and/or `@WritingConverter` for the custom types you have (see: [Mapping Solr Converter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-solr/docs/current/reference/html/solr.repositories.html#solr.mapping.mappingSolr) showing the configuration and [CustomConversionsTests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-solr/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/solr/core/convert/CustomConversionsTests.java#L65) for `Converter` samples).